# error during magento install error in file: data-install-1.6.0.0.php

Tags: magento

I ran into a problem during an the initial install of magento. I believe it was during the creation of the database tables and it possible timed out.

I dropped all tables in the database and now when I go back to try and do the initial install I get an error:

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 179362663215

The error log is as follows:

```
[code]a:5:{i:0;s:213:"Error in file: "/home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/data/directory_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:865:"#0 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')

#1 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installData('1.6.0.2')
#3 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
#4 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
#5 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}[/code]
```

Is there a way to "reset" the install?

Answer (score 1):

Magento install error - Exception printing is disabled

Here is a known error which can occur when installing Magento:
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Here is the solution:

1    Navigate to the "errors" folder.

2    Change local.xml.sample to local.xml
    You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.

3   Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

```
   protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'null',

    Change it to:

    protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

Save it.

4    Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
    That's it.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a little bit it allowed me to restart the install process without changing anything

Answer (score 0):

First, drop your database first.

Second, create new database for new magento installation.

Third, reinstall your magento.

The following error pointing to your database have duplicate entry in setup tables. When I started Magento, I always saw this error types.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:865:"#0 /home/mysite/beta.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')`

***PS. If allow to go admin panel, clear cache first. Then, try it again.***

Hope help